# WSGI Failed and any more

Tags: python, apache2, dashboard, wsgi

for the last five days I have been stuck on this problem to the point of trying all the examples I could find even though I knew it wouldn't work.

I want to put a plotly dashboard on an apache server accessible on the local network.

So I use the wsgi package for python 3, but without much success. Here is my wsgi.py:

```
import sys, os

sys.path.insert(0, "/var/www/html/dash/app")
sys.path.insert(0, "/var/www/html/dash/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages")

def application(environ, start8response):
    status = "200 OK"
    output = b"Hello World! \n"
    response_headers = [("Content-type", "text/plain"),
                        ("Content-Length", str(len(output)))]
    
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return [output]

from app import app as application
```

My .conf looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8050>
    #ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost#
    #DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dash/app#

    WSGIDaemonProcess app user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/dash/app/wsgi.py

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dash/app
    
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    #WSGIDaemonProcess app threads=5 user=www-data group=www-data python-path=/var/www/html/dash/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages python-home=/var/www/html/dash/venv/bin#
    #WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/dash/wsgi.py#

    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>

    <Directory /var/www/html/dash/app>
        #AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi
        WSGIProcessGroup app
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIScriptReloading On
        #Option Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews ExecCGI
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Finally, here are the errors I find in error.log when I try to access ip:8050:

```
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:20.903966 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:55724] mod_wsgi (pid=15054): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/html/dashAfc/app/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:20.904306 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:55724] mod_wsgi (pid=15054): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/dashAfc/app/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:20.914010 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:55724] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:20.914423 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:55724]   File "/var/www/html/dashAfc/app/wsgi.py", line 18, in <module>
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:20.914483 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:55724]     from app import app as application
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:20.914544 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:55724]   File "/var/www/html/dashAfc/app/app.py", line 8, in <module>
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:20.914572 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:55724]     app = dash.Dash(__name__, use_pages=True, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SPACELAB])
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:20.914630 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:55724]   File "/var/www/html/dashAfc/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 501, in __init__
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:20.914655 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:55724]     self.init_app()
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:20.914708 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:55724]   File "/var/www/html/dashAfc/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 565, in init_app
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:20.914734 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:55724]     self.enable_pages()
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:20.914787 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:55724]   File "/var/www/html/dashAfc/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 2023, in enable_pages
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:20.914812 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:55724]     self._import_layouts_from_pages()
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:20.914868 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:55724]   File "/var/www/html/dashAfc/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 1995, in _import_layouts_from_pages
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:20.914894 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:55724]     spec.loader.exec_module(page_module)
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:20.914947 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:55724]   File "/var/www/html/dashAfc/app/pages/pg3.py", line 8, in <module>
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:20.915038 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:55724]     import plotly.express as px
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:20.915094 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:55724]   File "/var/www/html/dashAfc/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/plotly/express/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:20.915119 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:55724]     raise ImportError(
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:20.915227 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:55724] ImportError: Plotly express requires pandas to be installed.
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:21.469357 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:57950] mod_wsgi (pid=15054): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/html/dashAfc/app/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:21.469831 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:57950] mod_wsgi (pid=15054): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/dashAfc/app/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:21.470619 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:57950] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:21.470900 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:57950]   File "/var/www/html/dashAfc/app/wsgi.py", line 18, in <module>
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:21.470927 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:57950]     from app import app as application
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:21.470984 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:57950]   File "/var/www/html/dashAfc/app/app.py", line 8, in <module>
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:21.471010 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:57950]     app = dash.Dash(__name__, use_pages=True, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SPACELAB])
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:21.471065 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:57950]   File "/var/www/html/dashAfc/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 501, in __init__
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:21.471091 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:57950]     self.init_app()
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:21.471144 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:57950]   File "/var/www/html/dashAfc/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 565, in init_app
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:21.471168 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:57950]     self.enable_pages()
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:21.471221 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:57950]   File "/var/www/html/dashAfc/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 2023, in enable_pages
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:21.471246 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:57950]     self._import_layouts_from_pages()
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:21.471300 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:57950]   File "/var/www/html/dashAfc/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 1995, in _import_layouts_from_pages
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:21.471325 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:57950]     spec.loader.exec_module(page_module)
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:21.471378 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:57950]   File "/var/www/html/dashAfc/app/pages/pg3.py", line 8, in <module>
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:21.471403 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:57950]     import plotly.express as px
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:21.471456 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:57950]   File "/var/www/html/dashAfc/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/plotly/express/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:21.471481 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:57950]     raise ImportError(
[Mon Aug 29 13:13:21.471573 2022] [wsgi:error] [pid 15054] [remote 172.22.0.11:57950] ImportError: Plotly express requires pandas to be installed.
```

I don't really know what to do anymore. I had read someone saying that they felt like a monkey typing on a keyboard. Funny at the time, but I feel that way now too.

All help is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: What is unclear about the `ImportError` you get? Do you have pandas installed as the error says?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I also tried to uninstall it and install it again, but nothing works.
I also checked www-data permissions on the modules, everything is ok.

I'm going around in circles.